# How to convert paragraphs to double quotes sentences in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, split, double-quotes, sentence

I have a text file having many paragraphs, i want to split it by sentences i.e. after every dot "." or ? it split and include the sentence in double Qoutes like:

This is a sentence.  This is an excited sentence! And do you think this is a question? so what then .

"This is a sentence."

"This is an excited sentence!"

"And do you think this is a question?"

"so what then."

and save it in text file all the sentences.

```
def splitParagraphIntoSentences(paragraph):

    import re
    sentenceEnders = re.compile('[.!?]')
    sentenceList = sentenceEnders.split(paragraph)
    return sentenceList

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = """This is a sentence.  This is an excited sentence! And do you think this is a question? so what to do then because many people will say this ok. and then what ?"""

   sentences = splitParagraphIntoSentences(p)
   for s in sentences:
       sentence=(s.strip())
   file = open("another.txt", "w")
   file.write(sentence)
   file.close()
```

it doesn't work, and not sure how to make each sentence in double quotes, any help  ???

Comment: First of all, I don't know if this is the result of not knowing well how to post code, but the indentation is not correct when you import `re`...I have just noticed that your doc strings are also not indented correctly...

Comment: i updated the question and code sample... can you help me to explain how can i make the sentences in double quotes too ?

Comment: See the modifications of the code in my answer, but the idea is that you could have simply written to the file also the double quotes by concatenating them with your sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you are asking, try to modify your code to the following one:

```
import re


def splitParagraphIntoSentences(paragraph):
    ''' break a paragraph into sentences
    and return a list '''

    sentenceEnders = re.compile('[.!?]')
    sentenceList = sentenceEnders.split(paragraph)
    return sentenceList

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = "This is a sentence. This is an excited sentence! And do you think this is a question? so what to do then because many people will say this ok. and then what ?"

    sentences = splitParagraphIntoSentences(p)

    file = open('another.txt', "w")

    for s in sentences:
        if s.strip():
            file.write('"' + s.strip() + '"\n')  # Add a newline after each sentence

    file.close()
```

In your case, instead of `p` you need first of course to read the file, since yours (I guess) was just a simplification.

Comment: got it, made these slight modification, thanks but it save sentences without double quotes.. how to do that , any suggestion ?

Comment: `print(' "this is a sentence with double quotes" ')`

Comment: @Pardoido What did you want to demonstrate with your comment? I am already writing to the file the sentences enclosed in double quotes.